# Different timezone when Airbite integrate SQL Server 2017 to Bigquery

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, airbyte

I am integrate data from SQL Server 2017 with CDC enable to BigQuery. I found that first full updated data seem to have a different timezone with later incrementally updated data, so that the first updated data will not be updated anymore.

Just like the image shown below, the column _ab_cdc_update_at has two datetime, 2023-04-14 12:44 and 2023-04-14 20:42, 2023-04-14 20:42 data are first full updated, and 023-04-14 12:44 data is later updated data which I just updated it in SQL Server.
First full updated datetime is correct as my local timezone CST, but the later incremental updated datetime became UTC.
Anyone have this problem? What can I configure to fix it?

[_ab_cdc_update_at has two timezone datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuInp.png)

What I have done:

- I built Airbyte on GKE via helm, and have set both Server and Scheduler to be the same timezone.
- SQL Server also be set in the same timezone